# I'm trying to make a Discord bot with Python but am encountering problems with client.run

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I'm trying to make a Discord bot with Python, but

```
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

is giving me an error:

> RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop error.

This is my full code:

```py
# !py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
import os
import discord

# making a new environment variable
os.environ['TOKEN'] = "MTA0Nzc3OTMzMjY2OTU5MTU3Mg.GUCNi9.Yro7C1zuxWoArhKYgJLXv7lmCdkcf0CQZhE7cc"

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

And this is the error:

```
---> 41 client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py in run(self, token, reconnect, log_handler, log_formatter, log_level, root_logger)
    826 
    827         try:
--> 828             asyncio.run(runner())
    829         except KeyboardInterrupt:
    830             # nothing to do here

~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py in run(main, debug)
     31     """
     32     if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
---> 33         raise RuntimeError(
     34             "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")
     35 

RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
```

If it helps, I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run this code.

Comment: You have just posted your bot's token on stackoverflow.  You should change it immediately as other people could take and use it. [How to do that here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/6470840524311-Why-can-t-I-copy-my-bot-s-token-).

Comment: Is there a reason you're running it as a jupyter notebook and not just as a python file?